# How to fetch data from multiple table in mysql order by date?

Tags: php, mysql

How to fetch the data from multiple table by date in mysql?

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    select 0 as case_no,amount , remarks, str_to_date(date,'%d/%m/%Y') as dt from ig_referance_paid where  referance = '$_GET[id]'    
     UNION ALL
   select case_no ,amount , 0 as remarks, str_to_date(date,'%d/%m/%Y') as dt from ig_referance_income where  referance = '$_GET[id]' 
) T1
ORDER BY dt
```

Can i get any better way to make simple. Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: You are widely open to SQL injection. Use parametrized queries.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for subquery:

```
SELECT 0 AS case_no,
       amount,
       remarks,
       STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS dt 
FROM ig_referance_paid 
WHERE referance = '$_GET[id]'    
UNION ALL
SELECT case_no,
       amount,
       0 AS remarks,
       STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS dt 
FROM ig_referance_income
WHERE referance = '$_GET[id]'
ORDER BY dt;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c2a90/2/0)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 0 AS case_no,
       amount,
       remarks,
       STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS dt 
FROM ig_referance_paid 
WHERE referance = '$_GET[id]'    
UNION ALL
SELECT case_no,
       amount,
       0 AS remarks,
       STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS dt 
FROM ig_referance_income
WHERE referance = '$_GET[id]'
```